# Installing monit 5.0.3 on FreeBSD

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring

Admittedly, I'm not very UNIX savvy but here's my question anyway.  I'm trying to install monit in my "user space" and am receiving this message:

> >./configure --prefix=/usr/home/peter
>   configure: creating ./config.status
>   config.status: creating Makefile
>   config.status: WARNING:  Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
>   config.status: creating config.h
>   config.status: config.h is unchanged
>   >make
>   make: Permission denied

My hosting provider says I have make permissions but that it is still trying to install in /usr/local where I have no permissions.  Anyone one have any thoughts?  modify configure file somehow?  I can't seem to find any documentation on configure options?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running "`configure --help`" to see if there are any other relevant options.  I haven't tried monit in particular, but sometimes, if you're trying to install an application from source, you may need GNU make (which you may need to also install and have in your path ahead of FreeBSD's make.

This is odd, though, as --prefix is often all that's needed to do what you want.

EDIT:  I Just tried an install of monit to /tmp/monit as a non-root user (using --prefix),  and it worked fine.  I just had to use "gmake" (GNU make, as installed from ports).  Give that a try.  (BTW, I had to un-tar the source file from /usr/ports/distfiles into /tmp in order for this to work.  You may not have enough permissions from within /usr/ports to do a build from there.)

Comment: gmake worked for me.  I'll have to remember that for next time.  Thanks.